# It's possible extend or shorten a p:chart on resize of the page?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, resize, jqplot

I would like update a chart size with the change of the browser's window if it's possible.

It is my code:

```
<b:column col-xs="12" col-md="12" >
    <p:chart widgetVar="foo" type = "pie" model="#{graphicBean.pieModel}" rendered="#{not empty graphicBean.pieModel}"/>
</b:column>
```

Comment: What is extend or shorten? more or less values? No not possibke afaic. unless jqplot has something for this. Or just scale it? Then look at the PF showcase and/or docs.

Answer (score 2):

The `<p:chart>` supports responsive mode. Set it to 'true'. The following line is from Primefaces documentation.

> In responsive mode, chart is redrawn when window is resized

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartView.lineModel1}" style="height:300px;" responsive="true"/>
```

Please refer [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/responsive.xhtml) for an example.